# How to use webpack to transform the await keyword to es5?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can't for the life of me figure out how to transform code using `await` to valid es5. I'm using webpack 3 and can successfully transform `async` functions to functions returning promises, but its erroring on `await`: `Module build failed: SyntaxError: ...: await is a reserved word`. I assumed I needed a particular `babel-loader` plugin, but I don't see one for `await`. Here's the relevant part of my webpack config:

```
     module: {   
        rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
              plugins: ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator"],
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

UPDATE:

Here's the relevant part of my webpack config now:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'nodent-loader',
            options: {
              promises: true,
              wrapAwait: true
            }
           },
           {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
              plugins: ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator"],
            }
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

And here's the code I'm trying to compile:

```
module.exports = async function() {
    var x = await wait()
}

async function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve()
        },1000)
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem of your config.  How you use await, I think that't the problem, Can you paste the code ?

Comment: I'm using await correctly: `await asyncFunction();` The plugins I'm using don't support converting await to es5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have `async` declared on the wrong function.

your `wait` function is not async. You call it, and it immediately returns a promise.

you need add `async` to `this.init`, which IS an async function. It doesn't return right away because it needs to `await` the promise to resolve.

See docs for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Ok i see. But surely those aren't syntax errors, which is what I got. It didn't get passed the `await wait()`.

Comment: I found this: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/. there should be a webpack version? Apparently generators are in es2015 so it uses those instead.